# inmobi landscape interstitial ads for android

Tags: android, landscape, ads, interstitial, inmobi

Does anybody know how to make inmobi interstitial ads only landscape orientation for Android?
I tried to send post request with parameter "d-orientation", but nothing happened.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("d-orientation", "3");
request.setRequestParams(map);
```

Comment: Answer from inmobi helpcenter: We currently do not support landscape orientation for interstitial ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from inmobi helpcenter: We currently do not support landscape orientation for interstitial ads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:ScreenOrientation="landscape"` for your respective activity.So that your activity is visible only in landscape mode.Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: No, it is not work. Inmobi send ad in portrait orientation and it is been cropped on application in landscape.